# Why customtkinter widgets are first white when created?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

It's a small detail but it's annoying for me because i notice this every time i create a new window, as you can see in the photos the background of the window is first white and then changed into '#1A1A1A' and i notice this colour change, and than in the other photo as you can see with the arrows the widgets are first white you can see the white rectangular boxes, how can i create the widgets directly whith the background color = '#1A1A1A' in order to not create them with the white starting color? Hope you can understand and help me, thanks here is an example code

```
from tkinter import *
import customtkinter
def function():
    win_bollettini = Toplevel(win)
    win_bollettini.resizable(False,False)
    win_bollettini.configure(bg='#1A1A1A')
    win_bollettini.title('Bollettini')
    casella_matricola = customtkinter.CTkEntry(win_bollettini, 
    corner_radius=8, width=150,       placeholder_text='Matricola', 
    border_color='#505050',border_width=3, fg_color='#282828', 
    text_color='white',font=('Courier', 17))
    casella_matricola.pack(padx=50,pady=(20,20))
    casella_n_bollettini = customtkinter.CTkEntry(win_bollettini,corner_radius=8,width=50,placeholder_text='Num',border_color='#505050',border_width=3,fg_color='#282828',text_color='white',font=('Courier',17))
    casella_n_bollettini.pack(pady=(0,17))
    check_cambio_primario = customtkinter.CTkCheckBox(win_bollettini, text='Cambio primario', font=('Courier', 17), text_color='white',fg_color='green', hover_color='#289253')
    check_cambio_primario.pack(pady=(0,20))
    check_to_normale = customtkinter.CTkCheckBox(win_bollettini, text='TO normale', font=('Courier', 17), text_color='white',fg_color='green', hover_color='#289253')
    check_to_normale.pack(pady=(0,20))
    check_to_con_primario = customtkinter.CTkCheckBox(win_bollettini, text='TO con primario', font=('Courier', 17), text_color='white',fg_color='green', hover_color='#289253')
    check_to_con_primario.pack(pady=(0,20))
    check_bltn_gia_fatti = customtkinter.CTkCheckBox(win_bollettini,text='Già iniziati',font=('Courier',17),text_color='white',fg_color='green',hover_color='#289253')
    check_bltn_gia_fatti.pack(pady=(0,20))
    check_curve = customtkinter.CTkCheckBox(win_bollettini,text='Curve',font=('Courier',17),text_color='white',fg_color='green',hover_color='#289253')
    check_curve.pack(pady=(0,20))
    selezione_n_secondari_curve = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(win_bollettini,values=['1','2','3','4','5'],width=53,corner_radius=7,fg_color='#1A1A1A',text_color='white',button_color='#3C3F41',border_color='#3C3F41',button_hover_color='#373737',dropdown_fg_color='#1A1A1A',dropdown_text_color='white',dropdown_hover_color='#2B2B2B')
    selezione_n_secondari_curve.set('1')
    n_secondari_curve = '1'
    selezione_n_secondari_curve.pack(pady=(0,40))
    btn_ok = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=win_bollettini, text='Fatto', font=('Courier', 16, 'bold'), width=10, corner_radius=9,fg_color='#072D56',hover_color='#072851',border_color='black',border_width=2)
    btn_ok.pack(pady=(0,20))
    win.eval(f'tk::PlaceWindow {str(win_bollettini)} center')
    win_bollettini.mainloop()
win = Tk()
button = Button(win,text='Click me',font=('Ink free',20),command=function)
button.pack(padx=30,pady=30)
win.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
win.mainloop()
```

Photo 1:

[image]

Photo 2:

[image]

I expect to solve this

Comment: What about hiding just after creating the top level window and showing after all the initialization works finished. You can use the ```withdraw()``` and ```deiconify()```.

Comment: Hi @relent95 thanks for the idea, on paper it seems good but i tried and it doesn't work properly probably i'm doing it wrong, can you help me? I created an other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76254044/trouble-hiding-and-showing-a-gui-with-withdraw-and-deiconify