# Trouble hiding and showing a GUI with withdraw() and deiconify()

Tags: python, tkinter, window

Probably i'm doing it wrong but my idea is to create a window hiding it right after created with "win.withdraw()", create the widgets and various settings, give to the computer 2 seconds for creating all the frames backgrounds ecc and then show the window when it's ready after all this initialization with "win.deiconify()", but in this way i see a blank window for 2 seconds and then the window is finally genereted, how to make this more fluid without noticing the white window?

```
from tkinter import *
import customtkinter
import time
def function():
    win.deiconify()
    win.mainloop()
win = Tk()
win.withdraw()
win.title('Automazione')
back = '#1A1A1A'
win.configure(bg=back)
win.resizable(False,False)
frame_sopra = Frame(win,bg='#1A1A1A')
frame_sopra.pack()
btn_ta = customtkinter.CTkButton(frame_sopra, text='TA', font=('Courier', 25), width=50,text_color='white',fg_color='#006640', hover_color='#005C40', corner_radius=10, border_width=3,border_color='black')
btn_ta.pack(side=RIGHT,padx=50,pady=(25,5))
btn_tv = customtkinter.CTkButton(frame_sopra, text='TV', font=('Courier', 25), width=50,text_color='white',fg_color='#284F55', hover_color='#284555', corner_radius=10, border_width=3,border_color='black')
btn_tv.pack(side=LEFT,padx=50,pady=(25,5))
frame_sotto = Frame(win,bg='#1A1A1A')
frame_sotto.pack()
check_ta = customtkinter.CTkCheckBox(frame_sotto,text='Targhette', font=('Courier', 17),text_color='white',fg_color='green',hover_color='#289253')
check_ta.pack(pady=(10))
check_fi = customtkinter.CTkCheckBox(frame_sotto,text='F.I.', font=('Courier', 17),text_color='white',fg_color='green',hover_color='#289253')
check_fi.pack(pady=(5,15))
frame_sotto2 = Frame(win,bg='#1A1A1A')
frame_sotto2.pack(pady=10)
btn_apri = customtkinter.CTkButton(frame_sotto2,text='Apri percorso',font=('Courier',15),text_color='white',fg_color='#323232',hover_color='#2D2D2D',corner_radius=10, border_width=2,border_color='black')
btn_apri.grid(row=0,column=0,pady=10,padx=(15,10))
check_ordini = customtkinter.CTkCheckBox(frame_sotto2,text='Ordini', font=('Courier', 17),text_color='white',fg_color='green',hover_color='#289253')
check_ordini.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=(0,10))
btn_bollettini = customtkinter.CTkButton(frame_sotto2,text='Bollettini',font=('Courier',15),text_color='white',fg_color='#323232',hover_color='#2D2D2D',corner_radius=10, border_width=2,border_color='black')
btn_bollettini.grid(row=1,column=0)
win.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
time.sleep(2)
function()
```

Thanks a lot i have this problem for months

Comment: Why do you need the two seconds delay?

Answer (score 1):

You should always call the `mainloop()` without blocking the event loop like calling the `time.sleep()`. If you want an artificial delay, use the `after()` to schedule a callable(function or method) like this.

```
...
win = Tk()
win.withdraw()
...
win.after(2000, win.deiconify) # The 2000 timeout is in ms.
win.mainloop()
```